# Regularly varying function represented with a slowly varying function

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to show that any regularly varying function $h(x)$ with index $\rho$ can be represented as $h(x)=x^\rho L(x)$, where $L(x)$ is a slowly varying function.

My attempt:

If $h$ is a regularly varying, then $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{h(tx)}{h(x)}=t^\rho \space \forall t>0$, it means that $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{h(tx)}{h(x)t^\rho}=1$ and here I am stuck...

Comment: What is a regularly varying function? If the definition is : $h:(0,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$ such that 
$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{h(tx)}{h(x)}=t^\rho \space \forall t>0$, then you can simply set $L(x)=h(x)/x^\rho$ and check that it is indeed slowly varying.

Comment: @zuggg Thanks, you helped me to understand that the expression $h(x)=x^\rho L(x)$ for a regularly varying function $h$ is nothing more but a claim that if a regularly varying function is divided by $x^\rho$ a slowly varying function must come out, and that claim is trivial to prove.